# asp.net mvc should calls wcf

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Greetings, 
I have a wcf service that exposes functionality to my wpf application. This works fine. 
I would like to create a web version and I am wondering how can I connect from my asp.net mvc application to my wcf service? Should I use the same approach as for WPF application (which uses Proxy to connect to the WCF Service. 
Is there any nice article how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a Service Reference to your MVC application and use the proxy just as you would in your WPF app.